# Linux real Ram usage

Tags: ubuntu, ram

Once i login through putty i see one ram usage and when run `free -m` i see another different one . which one is right? and whats the correct way to get real ram usage?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Out of the 244 that is shown as `used`, 46 is used by `buffers` and 126 is used by `cache`. The `buffers/cache` memory will be automatically freed when the memory gets low. So, the actual free memory is `Used - buffers/cache` and that is about 419 out of 489. The line `-/+ buffers/cache:` shows the actual RAM usage.